# Find values of b for which $f(x)=x^3+x^2+bx+6$ is increasing for all values of $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For the function defined by $f(x)$, find the values of $b$ that results in $f(x)$ increasing for all values of $x$.

I found the derivative: $f'(x) = 3x^2+2x+b$ and I know that it should always be equal to a value greater than 0, I just don't know how to find $b$.

Comment: Use the quadratic formula (with $c=b$) to find the roots of $f'(x)$ in terms of $b$. That will put some conditions on what $b$ can be.

Comment: Laars, I did that and got (-2 +- sq(4-12b))/6. What is the next step? I tried making that equation > 0, but I ended up getting b>0 and I don't know is that is correct. Is there a way to check my answer?

Comment: So when do we have roots in our derivative? Look at the discriminant. Then what happens when we don't have roots? Is it possible that $f$ increases everywhere? If we do have roots, you will need to use the second derivative test to find the inflection point and then everything to the right of the root on the concave up part and everything to the left of the concave down part will be your increasing regions.

Comment: I haven't learned how to do the second derivative test. This is a question to sum up what we have learned after the lesson about the first derivative test only. It is possible for the answer to be b>0? If you solve for the value of b, that is what I got using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Rewrite the derivative as
$$
f'(x) = 3x^2+2x+b=3\left(x^2+\frac 23x+\frac b 3 \right)=3\left(x+\frac 13\right)^2+ \frac {3b-1}3
$$ then just solve $$ 3b-1\geq0.$$

Comment: How did you get that equation, can you please explain the process to me?

Comment: @Kiran Yes, as the first term $3\left(x+\frac 13\right)^2 $ is always non negative, you just have to consider the second one $\frac {3b-1}3$ so you just want to make this last one non negative... giving $b\geq \dfrac13.$

Comment: By completing the square on the quadratic $3x^2+2x+b$.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track. Now subtracting $3x^2+2x$ from both sides, we get $b > -3x^2-2x$. If we find the minimum of the function on the left, we can get our bound for $b$. The derivative of $-3x^2-2x$ is $-6x-2 \implies -6x-2 = 0 \implies x = \frac{1}{3}$. Now we know that the bound is $b > 1/3$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.